# Excel VBA function returns an incorrect number of characters

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the Excel VBA function "Left" to get the left three characters of a string, but the function only returns two. The string has more than three characters, so I'm at a loss for why it would return fewer. The official documentation indicates that the function should return the number of characters requested or the entire string if the string is shorter than the requested character count.

[image: Code Snippet]

The error appears in the section below, but `Trim()` appears to be working correctly. I also can't step into the `Left()` function to see how it's handling the inputs.

```
part = Trim(part)
pref = Left(part, 3)
```

EDIT1: I changed the character count in the `Left()` function to see if it would change accordingly. `Left(part, 2)` returned 1 character (just `P`). It appears the function is systemically returning 1 fewer character than requested.

EDIT2: I also changed the `If` statement to accept one fewer character for events where `Left()` returned the incorrect quantity.

[image: Modified Code Snippet]

In the snippet above, a single `V` should be accepted but the code skipped to the line indicated by the arrow, which shows that the comparison was still false. This is leading me to believe that there is a non-printing character leading the entire string, but I don't know how to check for that.

Comment: Hmmm - you've probably got a leading character that `Trim` isn't removing. What does `Debug.Print Asc(Left(part, 1))` return?

Comment: @BigBen This just gives me a runtime error.

Comment: No parens, just a space after `Print`.

Comment: @BigBen ```Asc()``` gives me a runtime error, but copying the text output from ```Debug.Print``` and putting it through an ASCII converter gives me "10 10" which, according to an ASCII table, are newline characters. Is there another way to convert to ASCII in Excel VBA since ```Asc()``` doesn't work for me?

Comment: If you know what characters are the problematic ones, then just do `part = Replace(part, Chr(10),"")`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `AscW` throw an error?

Comment: @BigBen, ```AscW()``` also throws an error. Both are an error 5. Also, I know that ASCII 10 is an error for *this* particular input, but not a general case. I did something similar to what you described, and I'll post it as an answer later on.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there were non-printing characters preceding the first visible character in the strings. I used the following code to remove other potentially problematic characters:

```
part = Trim(part)
While Left(part, 1) < Chr(32) And Len(part) > 1
    part = Right(part, Len(part) - 1)
Wend
```

This offered a more general way to remove problematic leading characters.